# Remove single quotation mark followed by double quotation mark

Tags: php, xss

Using PHP, I have to detect '" (single quotation mark followed by double quotation mark) to prevent XSS.
thus, I implemented below function.

```
function xss_cleaner_new($input_str){
    $return_str = preg_replace('/"\'/','&l', &input_str);
    return $return_str;
}
```

However, it seems to detect only (first single quotation mark) rather than (single quotation mark followed by double quotation mark)

How can I detect '"(single quotation mark followed by double quotation mark) sucessfully?

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell the complete story as to why you would need to do this against XSS -> it sounds like you are implementing some sort of blacklist, which is not the best way in almost all situations.

Comment: Don't try to use regex to clean HTML. Either blat the entire thing through `htmlspecialchars` or use a DOM parser and some whitelisting rules of allowed elements, attributes and value of attributes (e.g. if you allow href, don't allow href="javascript:")

Comment: it works on my machine (except &input_str should be $input_str), not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: Quentin, could you tell me how I can avoid XSS like
(XSS like '"--></style></script><script>alert(0x000640)</script>)
by using htmlspecialchars?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting single quotation mark followed by double quotation mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302271/detecting-single-quotation-mark-followed-by-double-quotation-mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/'\"/","&l",$input_str);
```

Comment: Oooh, a game of spot-the-difference

Comment: It would help if you explained what you changed instead of making people look for the changes (which are tiny).

Comment: @Quentin OP is trying to replace `double quotation followed by single quotation` instead of `single quotation followed by double quotation`

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it. What you say you want is to match a single quotation mark followed by a double quotation mark.  But just review your regex and think it through.

You have a non-interpolated PHP string literal `'/"\'/'` being fed into your function call, which contains an escaped apostrophe. The value of the string literal is `/"'/`, so now it's a `/`-delineated regex.  Take away the `/`s because we already said it's a regex, and you get `"'`, or, a **double quote followed by a single quote**, the exact opposite of what you want.  Working the other way, we can flip them (`'"`), delineate it with `/`s to signify its regexhood (`/'"/`), then quote it with apostrophes and escape out the apostrophes contained within so that the string literal isn't ended prematurely (`'/\'"/'`), and you're back where you started, only you don't have the mistake.